Chrome: how to prevent changing color setting with Chrome Group Policy ADMX Templates?
Finally I installed the Chrome Group Policy ADMX Templates on a windows 11 pc but I didn't find any option to prevent editing. Maybe I'm missing something...

What do you mean when you say "...to stop editing"? Do you mean that you don't know how to save the settings/policy changes you have applied, as in, you are unfamiliar with how the Group Policy modification tool works in Windows, or you are unable to find a specific setting within the Chrome policies? Or something else. Also, you have posted what APPEARS to be an update to your question in the Answers section. Note that this site is not a forum. ALL information for the question, including updates, should be here. The Answer area is only for answers.

Did you intend for this to be an answer to the question you asked above, or an update or clarification to it? If it is an answer, please make that more explicitly clear using the EDIT button down here. If you're instead adding more information to your question, delete this answer and use the EDIT button in the question to add the information. Please note, however, that your question (and this answer) are not very clear. Please carefully read and re-read what you've written and do what you can to make them as clear as you are able.
